# Captcha Pages Do Not Display Authentication Status

Tags: bug, status-completed, login, captcha, authentication

*NOTE: If this has already been fixed, sorry. I just haven't gotten a CAPTCHA in some time, so can't see what's happened.*

I've noticed that, when you get a **CAPTCHA**, at the top, **<strike>it always says "Login"</strike>it doesn't say anything, even if you're already logged in**. This was very unnerving the first few times I got it, while compose a question for a long period of time. When I saw that <strike>it said "Login"</strike>it said nothing instead of my display name, I thought that my session had ended. Thus, this may be confusing, the first time you see it.

I'm not sure if this is a bug, but if it is status-bydesign, I think that CAPTCHA pages should reflect authentication status, too.

**UPDATE:** Here's a pic! Notice, no logged in status at the top, not even "login"!
[image: CAPTCHA]

Answer (score 1):

In fact, it doesn't even say Login. See here: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/captcha.